# coefficient of determination (R2): why is SSR not equal to 1- SSE/SST?

Tags: r, regression, goodness-of-fit

I feel like this should be straight forward but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My understanding is

1 = (SSR/SST) + (SSE/SST)

SST = total sum of squares

SSR = regression sum of squares

SSE = residual sum of squares

With that logic, 1 - SSE == SSR

I wrote these functions in R:

```
r2<-function(preds,actual){
  rss <- sum((preds - actual) ^ 2)
  tss <- sum((actual - mean(actual))^2)
  rsq <- 1 - (rss/tss)
  rsq
 }

r2A<-function(preds,actual){
   reg <- sum((preds - mean(actual)) ^ 2)
   tss <- sum((actual - mean(actual))^2)
   reg/tss
 }
```

And I tested my functions

```
library(MASS)
old<-data.frame(EuStockMarkets[1:1700,])
new<-data.frame(EuStockMarkets[1701:1860,])
mA<-glm(DAX~., data=old, family=gaussian)
p<-predict(mA, new, type="response")
```

with these results

```
library(MASS)
old<-data.frame(EuStockMarkets[1:1700,])
new<-data.frame(EuStockMarkets[1701:1860,])
mA<-glm(DAX~., data=old, family=gaussian)
p<-predict(mA, new, type="response")

r2(p,new$DAX)
>0.9160558
r2A(p,new$DAX)
>0.6447832
library(mlr)
measureRSQ(new$DAX,p)
>0.9160558
```

They're clearly not the same. Could anyone shed some insight on what's going on? I think this might be a statistical concept problem and not a coding issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You need to multiply *both* sides of your first expression by SST!  (I've done similar before... :)

Comment: @jbowman Thanks! Do you mean SST = SSR + SSE?

Comment: You have $$1 = \frac{SSR}{SST} + \frac{SSE}{SST}$$ so you can say $$1-\frac{SSE}{SST} = \frac{SSR}{SST}$$ (this is because from basic algebra, if $1 = a+b$, then $1-b=a$). Equivalently, you have $$SST- SSE = SSR.$$

Comment: Thanks to the both of you! Sorry, that was dumb--thanks for writing out the equations so I could see my mistake.